# Shell command for compress and backup?

Tags: shell-script

```
ls com x y z
```

I want to compress and backup the files x,y,z into the com directory.
Also I want to see by how much these files have been compressed.

Comment: Unclear: You have _what_ files? What you have in your question is a `ls` command line with no indication of what the operands are or why you are running `ls` on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionaly tar is the tool to combine multiple files into one and some form of zip is used for compression however 7z provides optimal performance when seeking is available;

```
7z a "com/backup$(date --iso-8601).7z" x y z
```

Compression ratio and details can be obtained with

```
7z l $FILE
```

Or

```
du -csh com/*
```

If you are going to back up more than once you may want a backup that uses diff (like rdiff-backup). If you are going to send backups over the network, rsync or file system snapshot shipping is advised.

Be sure to read the manual of any command before you use it

```
man 7z
```

Comment: I am not using it for linux. I am using these commands to backup files on the sever using Putty.

Comment: PuTTY is a SSH client.  Your server runs - presumably - a Linux or Unix-like OS.